# What is the blue circle in python dash app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am new to dash and I don't know what exactly the blue circle is in the app does.

Attached is the same for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVcsY.png

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? Asked the authors?

Comment: what app ? Add ulr for this page and code.

Answer (score 4):

That is only visible when running in debug mode. Use `app.run_server(debug=False)` to hide it. It allows you to view or hide errors in the browser, and view the callback structure of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep debug mode on (for other functionality like hot reload) and just turn off the debug menu by setting `app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_ui=False)`.

However, this will also hide Dash warnings, which you can still find in the console, but are harder to notice.